# Focus / selection problems with ToolStripContainer

Tags: c#, winforms, focus, .net-4.6.1

I have a `Form` that contains:

- at least 2 `Control`s that implement an interface and are selectable - on form load only the first control is visible (each of these `Control`s has a `MouseDown` handler that `Select`s or focuses itself);
- a tool strip that contains a custom ToolStripItem like a slider (track bar) for zoom;
- the zoom track bar works on the currently focused `Control` which implements that interface (the user can click on one of the Control and the track bar remembers the zoom percents for each of the two Controls and updates itself to match the currently focused Control's zoom percent);
- everything enumerated above is inside a `ToolStripContainer`.

On form load the first `Control` is focused automatically. Then:

1. I make the second control visible, and
2. I click on the second `Control`,
3. It gains focus.

If then I:

1. Click on the first control again,
2. It does not gain focus.

If:

1. The form loses focus and then
2. The form gains the focus by clicking on the first `Control`,
3. The first `Control` gains focus;
4. The second Control then gains focus on clicking it without needing to unfocus the form.

The problem seems to be that the `FindControlWithFocus` static method does not understand the `ToolStripContainer` control. It searches in it for a focused control, and it does not find any (although the `ToolStripContainer` is the only direct child control in my `Form`).

## The code

I have an event handler attached to all the Enter events of all the controls in the Form, including the Form. In this handler, I call the `FindControlWithFocus` with this control as a parameter to find the most close to the surface (not deep) control that has focus.

The problem is that, after the second child is made visible, `FindControlWithFocus` returns `null` when, without first defocusing the `Form`, clicking on the on the first `Control`.

```
public static Control FindControlWithFocus(Control parent)
{
    if (parent.Focused)
    {
        return parent;
    }

    foreach (Control ctl in parent.Controls)
    {
        if (ctl.Focused)
        {
            return ctl;
        }

        Control child = FindControlWithFocus(ctl);

        if (child != null)
        {
            return child;
        }
    }

    return null;
}

private void Ce_FocusedControlChanged(object sender,
    FocusMovedEventArgs e)
{
    Control c = Utils.FindControlWithFocus(e.FocusedControl);

    while (c != null && // (a)
        !Utils.TypeImplements(c.GetType(), typeof(IClocksView)))
    {
        c = c.Parent;
    }

    if (c != null) // (b)
    {
        LastFocusedTimersView = c as IClocksView;
    }
}
```

## Tracepoints

1. On line marked `(a)` above: `Control that got focus: {e.FocusedControl}; Surfacemost element with focus: {c};`
2. On line marked `(b)` above: `surfacemost parent that is IClocksView: {c}`

In the Output panel I have these lines at the start of the program (until I start clicking):

```
Control that got focus: {System.Windows.Forms.ToolStripContainer}; Surfacemost element with focus: null;
surfacemost parent that is IClocksView: null
Control that got focus: {System.Windows.Forms.ToolStripContentPanel, BorderStyle: System.Windows.Forms.BorderStyle.None}; Surfacemost element with focus: null;
surfacemost parent that is IClocksView: null
Control that got focus: {Text = "F&ull-screen" CheckState = Unchecked}; Surfacemost element with focus: null;
surfacemost parent that is IClocksView: null
Control that got focus: {cs_timed_silver.MainForm, Text: Timed Silver - new file}; Surfacemost element with focus: {Text = "F&ull-screen" CheckState = Unchecked};
Control that got focus: {cs_timed_silver.MainForm, Text: Timed Silver - new file}; Surfacemost element with focus: {System.Windows.Forms.ToolStripContentPanel, BorderStyle: System.Windows.Forms.BorderStyle.None};
Control that got focus: {cs_timed_silver.MainForm, Text: Timed Silver - new file}; Surfacemost element with focus: {System.Windows.Forms.ToolStripContainer};
Control that got focus: {cs_timed_silver.MainForm, Text: Timed Silver - new file}; Surfacemost element with focus: {cs_timed_silver.MainForm, Text: Timed Silver - new file};
Control that got focus: {cs_timed_silver.MainForm, Text: Timed Silver - new file}; Surfacemost element with focus: null;
surfacemost parent that is IClocksView: null
```

When I click on the second `Control`, the output is:

```
Control that got focus: {System.Windows.Forms.TableLayoutPanel, BorderStyle: System.Windows.Forms.BorderStyle.None}; Surfacemost element with focus: {ClockDataGridView ID = 1};
surfacemost parent that is IClocksView: {ClockDataGridView ID = 1}
Control that got focus: {SplitterView: TimerGroupListView & SplitterView}; Surfacemost element with focus: {ClockDataGridView ID = 1};
surfacemost parent that is IClocksView: {ClockDataGridView ID = 1}
Control that got focus: {System.Windows.Forms.SplitterPanel, BorderStyle: System.Windows.Forms.BorderStyle.None}; Surfacemost element with focus: {ClockDataGridView ID = 1};
surfacemost parent that is IClocksView: {ClockDataGridView ID = 1}
Control that got focus: {SplitterView: ClockListView & ClockDataGridView}; Surfacemost element with focus: {ClockDataGridView ID = 1};
surfacemost parent that is IClocksView: {ClockDataGridView ID = 1}
Control that got focus: {System.Windows.Forms.SplitterPanel, BorderStyle: System.Windows.Forms.BorderStyle.None}; Surfacemost element with focus: {ClockDataGridView ID = 1};
surfacemost parent that is IClocksView: {ClockDataGridView ID = 1}
Control that got focus: {ClockDataGridView ID = 1}; Surfacemost element with focus: {ClockDataGridView ID = 1};
surfacemost parent that is IClocksView: {ClockDataGridView ID = 1}
Control that got focus: {System.Windows.Forms.Panel, BorderStyle: System.Windows.Forms.BorderStyle.None}; Surfacemost element with focus: {System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewComboBoxEditingControl, Items.Count: 2};
Control that got focus: {System.Windows.Forms.Panel, BorderStyle: System.Windows.Forms.BorderStyle.None}; Surfacemost element with focus: {System.Windows.Forms.Panel, BorderStyle: System.Windows.Forms.BorderStyle.None};
Control that got focus: {System.Windows.Forms.Panel, BorderStyle: System.Windows.Forms.BorderStyle.None}; Surfacemost element with focus: {ClockDataGridView ID = 1};
surfacemost parent that is IClocksView: {ClockDataGridView ID = 1}
Control that got focus: {System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewComboBoxEditingControl, Items.Count: 2}; Surfacemost element with focus: {System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewComboBoxEditingControl, Items.Count: 2};
Control that got focus: {System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewComboBoxEditingControl, Items.Count: 2}; Surfacemost element with focus: {System.Windows.Forms.Panel, BorderStyle: System.Windows.Forms.BorderStyle.None};
Control that got focus: {System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewComboBoxEditingControl, Items.Count: 2}; Surfacemost element with focus: {ClockDataGridView ID = 1};
surfacemost parent that is IClocksView: {ClockDataGridView ID = 1}
Control that got focus: {System.Windows.Forms.Panel, BorderStyle: System.Windows.Forms.BorderStyle.None}; Surfacemost element with focus: {System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewComboBoxEditingControl, Items.Count: 2};
Control that got focus: {System.Windows.Forms.Panel, BorderStyle: System.Windows.Forms.BorderStyle.None}; Surfacemost element with focus: {System.Windows.Forms.Panel, BorderStyle: System.Windows.Forms.BorderStyle.None};
Control that got focus: {System.Windows.Forms.Panel, BorderStyle: System.Windows.Forms.BorderStyle.None}; Surfacemost element with focus: {ClockDataGridView ID = 1};
surfacemost parent that is IClocksView: {ClockDataGridView ID = 1}
Control that got focus: {System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewComboBoxEditingControl, Items.Count: 2}; Surfacemost element with focus: {System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewComboBoxEditingControl, Items.Count: 2};
Control that got focus: {System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewComboBoxEditingControl, Items.Count: 2}; Surfacemost element with focus: {System.Windows.Forms.Panel, BorderStyle: System.Windows.Forms.BorderStyle.None};
Control that got focus: {System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewComboBoxEditingControl, Items.Count: 2}; Surfacemost element with focus: {ClockDataGridView ID = 1};
surfacemost parent that is IClocksView: {ClockDataGridView ID = 1}
```

When I click on the first `Control` without first defocusing the Form, the output is:

```
Control that got focus: {System.Windows.Forms.TableLayoutPanel, BorderStyle: System.Windows.Forms.BorderStyle.None}; Surfacemost element with focus: null;
surfacemost parent that is IClocksView: null
Control that got focus: {SplitterView: ClockListView & ClockDataGridView}; Surfacemost element with focus: null;
surfacemost parent that is IClocksView: null
Control that got focus: {System.Windows.Forms.SplitterPanel, BorderStyle: System.Windows.Forms.BorderStyle.None}; Surfacemost element with focus: null;
surfacemost parent that is IClocksView: null
Control that got focus: {ClockListView ID = 1}; Surfacemost element with focus: null;
surfacemost parent that is IClocksView: null
Control that got focus: {cs_timed_silver.ClockFlowLayoutPanel, BorderStyle: System.Windows.Forms.BorderStyle.None}; Surfacemost element with focus: null;
surfacemost parent that is IClocksView: null
```

The problem is that on the last line above, the value is `null`. I need it to be `{ClockListView ID = 1}`.

Comment: Can you please share what are you trying to achieve, may be someone can be able to provide a alternate solution and that would also help understand your code better

Comment: @Anil I have updated the question.